# check box is not clicking using selenium ide

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to check checkbox using selenium IDE using click or check both. It is not checking at all check box. Can any one help me ?

html code for check box is:

```
<input id="iAgree" type="checkbox" name="iAgree" checked="checked">
```

I have used below IDE code:

```
check id=iAgree
check id=iAgree

or click id=iAgree
```

Please let me know where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
clickAt  | id=iAgree
```

Let me know its working or not.

```
click |  xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox']) |
```

Comment: I have used it already.It is checking check box but its value is not getting true.In my web application when we check checkbox,disabled submit button get enabled.While using click At,check box is checked but its values is not becoming true,Hence its not working for me.

Comment: click  | xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox'])  this will may work

Comment: used this :<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//input[@type='checkbox'</td>
 <td></td>
</tr> getting error message as : [error] Invalid xpath [2]: //input[@type='checkbox'

Comment: <tr> <td>click</td> <td>xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox'])</td> <td></td> </tr> ..

Comment: i have used as per your instruction.Getting below error message :info] Executing: |click | xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox') | |
[error] Invalid xpath [2]: (//input[@type='checkbox')

Comment: please closed [] check your target, its xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox'), missing  ]..It should be xpath=(//input[@type='checkbox'])

Comment: hi ,thanx for your responce......but this code is not working with it,testcase is pass but check box is not checked.It's html code is like that: when check box is not checked then HTML code is :<div class="cl-iagree-chk">
<div id="iAgree" class="checkbox" style="background-position: center 0pt;">
<input id="iAgree" type="checkbox" name="iAgree">
</div>
</div>

Comment: is it possible for you to share URL?

Comment: When html code is checked then html code is :<div class="cl-iagree-chk">
<div id="iAgree" class="checkbox" style="background-position: center -62px;">
<input id="iAgree" type="checkbox" name="iAgree" checked="checked">
</div> when check box is checked ,then only submit button get enabled.

Comment: last try   click  | xpath=(//*[@class="checkbox"])  OR class=checkbox  OR name=iAgree OR //div[@class='checkbox']

Answer (score 0):

I can do this with this code:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>Xpath of the checkbox</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I hope this will help. :)